# How to add a column of one table to other table using MySQL and Node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have categories and subcategories DB tables which are created by using MySQL. Currently sub-category table has category ID. I want to add category name also to sub-categories table.

How can I do this? Do I have to use LEFT join?

**admin.service.js**

```
try {
            const res = await this.db.sub_categories.findAll({where:{isDelete:false},
            include:[
                {model: this.db.categories, attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt", 'isActive', 'isDelete'] }, required: false}
            ]});
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));;
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
```

**admin.controller.js**

```
api.get('/subcategories', async(req,res,next)=>{
        try {
            const resp = await adminService.adminServiceFunc(req);
            res.status(constants.STATUS_200);
            next(resp);
        }catch(err){
            res.status(constants.STATUS_500);
            next(err.message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: When talking about "table" in terms of HTML and SQL, do try and be a bit more specific since both have an entirely different opinion on what that is.

Comment: done @tadman. Added which type of table it is